# SQL Server spatial query : import spatial information from Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server

I have an Excel sheet containing geographic information about US counties as follows:

```
NAME, STATE, latitude, Longitude
```

I would like to import this information into a SQL Server database directly using data import/export service.

However, I want to merge latitude, longitude columns from the Excel sheet and store the information in SQL Server as `Geography` or `Geometry` data type.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: And I am looking to do this by sql query . Otherwise I will have to write a code to retrive data from excel sheet and then put it into sql server by merging two columns.

Answer (score 0):

The import/export wizard is difficult to work with and I don't think you can write a complicated query to transform the lat long to geography but you can try this from SQL management studio.

```
 SELECT * INTO Your_Table FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\temp\testimportxlsx.xlsx',
 'SELECT ID, Lat, long, sp_geography = geography::STGeomFromText(''Point('' + CAST(Longitude AS VARCHAR(50)) 
 + '' '' + CAST(Latitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + '')'', 4326)  FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

This assumes your spreadsheet has the fields lat, long and ID.  It writes a new field called sp_geography that is the transformed lat and long fields into a field of datatype geography.

You may have to download and install the ACE provider.  If so search for the error message.